# Lateral (bending) stiffness of a helical compression spring

Tags: classical-mechanics, spring

Does a helical compression spring have uniform lateral (bending) stiffness throughout its length?

Suppose I exert a force radially along a certain height of the spring, and that force rotates along the cross-sectional plane of the spring helix, would the lateral bending be the same?

In other words perhaps, would the spring behave like a radially loaded shaft?

Answer (score 2):

For big rotations it is intuitively not like a shaft, because the spring would unwind, or become more thightly wound. this happens not equally across the springs lenght, because it is attached to something there. For small rotations it might approach a shaft, but it is not the same.