# Stiffness for helical spring under lateral bending force

Tags: elasticity, solid-mechanics

The stiffness for a helical spring under axial loads is

$$k_\text{axial}=\frac{F_\text{axial}}{\delta_{axial}}=\frac{Gd^4}{8n D^3}\, ,$$

where $G$ is the shear modulus, $d$ the wire diameter, $D$ the coil diameter, and $n$ the number of coils.

What is the corresponding formula (of reduced stiffness) for

$$k_\text{lateral}=\frac{F_\text{lateral}}{\delta_{lateral}}=?$$

There is a [related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/467196/lateral-bending-stiffness-of-a-helical-compression-spring) without a quantitative answer.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't likely to be an easily derived formula - under axial loads the forces on any cross section are the same so you can calculate fairly easily, loaded from the side they aren't. The cross-sections parallel to the force have a bending moment, the cross sections normal to it have pure torque, and those in between have a blend, so there'd probably be some complicated integrals involved to get something analytical.

You might want to do a computational finite element analysis or some simulations, and then extrapolate. There is some scaling that can be figured out from first principles.

The stiffness will be proportional to $d^4$ because the second moment of area / polar moment of inertia for bending moments and torque both scale with $d^4$. It will also be proportional to $G$. It's probably inversely proportional to $nL^2$, where $L$ is the total length - the bending moment or torque is proportional at each location to $FL$ for small deflection, each coil will rotate slightly for a given torque so rotation $\theta$ is proportional to $n$, and for small angles (and small forces), lateral displacement=$L\theta$. It would get non-linear for larger forces and larger displacements, so $F/\delta$ wouldn't be constant (but the total angle should be).

So it should be $k_{lateral}=\frac{AGd^4}{nL^2D^B}$ for very small forces and displacements, where $A$ and $B$ are constants to be determined - testing a few different physical springs or doing FEA simulations on a few should let you calculate $A$ and $B$

And for larger forces up to the elastic limit, it's probably $\frac{M}{\theta}=\frac{CGd^4}{nD^B}$, relating a moment $M$ applied to the spring to the angle between root and tip $\theta$, where $C$ is a different constant.

There might be something I've missed, so if you do do tests to calculate the constants, check that the exponents of $d$, $L$, $n$ seem right too